# Como incluir um arquivo que está dentro de outra pasta no mesmo servidor

Tags: php, wordpress, servidor

Já vi diversas outras perguntas parecida aqui na SO e fora da comunidade, mas nenhuma foi realmente útil, algumas opções que na teoria deveriam ter funcionado, mas de alguma forma não funcionou.

Atualmente gerencio um Droplet na [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) onde utilizo o painel de controle da [Runcloud](https://runcloud.io/), no servidor tenho 3 sites configurado, sendo que 2 utilizam o Wordpress e 1 para guardar arquivos.

```
/home/runcloud/webapps/
                      /domain1.com/
                                  /plugins/meu-plugin/...
                      /domain2.com/
                                  /wp-content/plugins/meu-plugin/...
                      /domain3.com/
                                  /wp-content/plugins/meu-plugin/...
```

Como eu poderia incluir um arquivo que esta dentro do `domain1.com` nos meus dois sites Wordpress.

A ideia e criar um plugin para fazer a requisição desse arquivos, ai em vez de enviar o plugin para ambos os sites, eu apenas envio as atualizações para o `domain1.com`

Já tentei utilizar as seguintes opções:

```
 include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../../plugins/meu-plugin/plugin.php');

 $file = '/home/runcloud/webapps/domain1.com/plugins/meu-plugin/plugin.php';
 include($file);
```

na teoria deveria funcionar, mas de alguma forma não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema de uma maneira "*fácil*" por assim dizer, estava utilizando **NGINX** que e o padrão da [Runcloud](https://runcloud.io/) e por algum motivo não estava funcionando, então criei outro Droplet e instalei o **LAMP** padrão que a  [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) disponibiliza, depois configurei meus sites, depois disso funcionou perfeitamente a inclusão do arquivo, acredito que seja por esta utilizando o **apache**, o que ficou "bugado" foi apenas o style e o js de dentro do arquivo, mas isso foi facilmente resolvido adicionado apenas o caminho da pasta do Wordpress nos arquivo `'/wp-content/plugins/meu-plugin/css/style.css'`.

```
Fiz um plugin para chamar o arquivo e adicionei dentro do diretório dos plugin do Wordpress
include('/var/www/dominio.com/meu_plugin/plugin.php');

/var/www/
        /domain1.com/
                    /meu_plugin/plugin.php
                    /public_html/wp-content/plugins/meu-plugin/plugin-include.php
```

Não fiz o teste mas acredito que também funcione fora da pasta do domínio `/var/www/`.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer include a partir com o link de forma directa.

`include(https:http://www.example.com/home/runcloud/webapps/domain1.com/plugins/meu-plugin/plugin.php');`

muda o `www.example.com/` para o teu site.

ou então podes exprimentar:
`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/plugins/meu-plugin/plugin.php');` 
sem os `..` mas isto depende do que tiveres definido como **root** do teu server.

Comment: já tentei isso, tentei até bater tambor e nada parece funciona, os arquivos estão nos mesmos caminho do exemplo, só alterei o nome do plugin mesmo porque ele e extenso.